# PHP: matching MIME with in_array

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an array holding a list of "good" mime types:

```
public $imageMimes = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/bmp', 'image/tiff');
```

And I'm testing it:

```
if (in_array($this->data['PictureForm']['file']['type'], $imageMimes)) {
...}
```

When I print the needle variable, I get image/png, but no match? Any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: What if you put a string `'image/png'` instead of `$this->data['VideoForm']['file']['type']`? If it works - then what you have in that variable is not exactly what you think. So use `var_dump` to find it out

Comment: I put: if (in_array('image/png', $imageMimes)) and it didn't match :(

Comment: and if you `var_dump($imageMimes)`?

Comment: `print_r($this->data['VideoForm']['file']['type'])`

Comment: it appears you're trying to validate an uploaded file... DONT'T DO IT THIS WAY. the **user-provided** `['type']` field is trivial to forge. Use server-side tools to determine mime-type, e.g. http://php.net/finfo_file

Comment: It's coming up as blank. If it's set as public, it shouldn't be out of scope, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using it to validate a file. Also: the videoMimes was accidental. It's all imageMimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need to use `$this->imageMimes` not `$videoMimes`

So you made 2 mistakes:

1. You tried to access a local variable (that doesn't exist), instead of object property
2. You used a wrong name for it